# How to reordering a numpy array (matrix) such that Matrix = [ Identity | Residue ] (just moving columns)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np

_list = [[1,-1,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 1,-1],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,-1, 1, 0, 0]]

matrix = np.array(_list)
print(matrix)

print('=='*50)
```

Searching for a identity submatrix (will always exist)

Reordering matrix such that (just moving columns)

matrix = [ Identity | Residue ]

```
# _list = [[1, 0, 0, 0,||-1,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#          [0, 1, 0, 0,|| 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
#          [0, 0, 1, 0,|| 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1,-1],
#          [0, 0, 0, 1,|| 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 1, 0]]

_list = [[1, 0, 0, 0,-1,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1,-1],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 1, 0]]

matrix = np.array(_list)
print(matrix)
```

How to solve this?

Any idea? Some function that allows to do this on Numpy?

Comment: Can the rows and columns be rearranged?

Comment: Check "my answer"

Answer (score 0):

[@abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia)'s copyright [StackOverflow en español]

```
import numpy as np

_list = [[1,-1,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 1,-1],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,-1, 1, 0, 0]]

matrix = np.array(_list)

I = np.identity(matrix.shape[0], dtype=int)
aux = set(tuple(c) for c in I.tolist())

residuo = []
for col in matrix.T:
  if tuple(col) in aux:
    aux.remove(tuple(col))
  else:
    residuo.append(col)

result = np.concatenate((I, np.array(residuo))).T
```

This solve my problem!